# IF formula wont return TRUE because one cell is being populated from another cell

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

Ive run into a minor issue. Im using an IFS formula to compare two cells. If they are identical, then "Y", if they are not "X". The formula works fine but the issue im running into is that one of the cells is drawing its data from a different cell using the "=" formula. Is there a way to get google sheets to recognize that cell as actual data that matches?

Here is link to the spreadsheet in question:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uoWiyyZOC0BM8jrqgeleQCQAlznyBNTLh3cYFDJfuhI/edit#gid=1001661705

Im comparing cell D3 & C3 on "Scott S." worksheet. Cell C3 however, is being populated using "=Scores!M2". Google sheets wont return a "true" value because of this.

Is there a way around it using an app script or a different formula im not thinking of?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra space before Miami in Scores!J2, that's why it's not recognizing as match

Answer (score 2):

Your formula is correct. You have space or few other invisible characters in-front of data on `Scores` sheet. Remove those character and then use below formula-

```
=MAP(C3:C48,D3:D48,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(a="",,IF(a=b,"Y","X"))))
```

With this formula, you do not need to drag down the formula to each cell. It will automatically spill results.

[image]